# When exactly do three vectors form a triangle, and when do they not?

Tags: vectors, triangles

> **Question:** (I made it up) Given three vectors $\vec {AB}, \vec {BC},\vec {CA}$; what is the *complete* method to prove that they form a triangle.

I know about the triangle law of addition, and that if $\vec {AB}+ \vec {BC}+\vec {CA}=0$, then these vectors may form a triangle.

However, my text book gives one example of: $\vec {AB}=3i-j-2k;  \vec {BC}=6i-2j-4k;\vec {CA}=9i-3j-6k$ where it notes that even though these three add up to zero, yet they do **not**  form a triangle.

My textbook doesn't give us a list of "checks" that need to be made on a given set of three vectors so as to check if they form a valid triangle.

I don't want to fall prey to examples of vectors as above, so I require one such list.

*I know 2-3 questions have been asked before on this topic but they're all having scattered theory and mine is an attempt to clear my doubts while unifying all steps together.*

Comment: They form a degenerate triangle, i.e. a triangle with zero area.

Comment: @MarceloFornet So, am I only to make two checks - zero area and vector sum$=0$?

Comment: Exactly. If the $sum=0$ condition holds then the area is $0$ if two of them are colinears, so it is an easy check.

Comment: @MarceloFornet What about coplanarity and related stuff?

Comment: Three vector are always coplanar.

Comment: @MarceloFornet If that's the case, please post a complete answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56309/discussion-between-marcelo-fornet-and-gaurang-tandon).

Comment: @MarceloFornet But aren't three "points" always coplanar? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity I was talking about three vectors...

Comment: You are right about this, but if the sum is zero you can be sure the are coplanar since the are linearly dependent and one of them belongs to the plane generated by the other 2.

Comment: To check that the resulting points aren’t colinear, compute the determinant $\tiny{\begin{vmatrix}&\vec{BC}-\vec{AB}&\\&\vec{CA}-\vec{AB}&\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether $3$ vectors form a non-degenerate triangle, i.e. a triangle with positive area, you only need to check if the sum of them is $0$ and the are not colinear.

$3$ vectors that sums $0$ can be written as $\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} + \vec{CA} = 0$ so $\vec{AB} + \vec{BC} = -\vec{CA}$. The are not linearly independent so they are coplanar.

Comment: Ok. I'll accept your answer in a day or two provided there's no better answers.

Comment: Note: if the question allows, we might also do $\vec{AB} \pm \vec{BC} \pm \vec{CA} = 0$ i.e. reverse the direction of individual vectors without changing their magnitude in order to form a triangle.